# Inkscape measure tool gives unexpected results

Tags: svg, inkscape, measurement

I'm working with Inkscape 1.1 on an iMac running 10.14.6.

I'm working on making a grid that has 4 rows and 7 columns.  Each cell is 39mm X 39mm with a 5.3 mm line between the rows.

I've gotten the grid created but I'm running into a problem with the measurement tool reporting incorrect values.

Each line, with the exception of the bottom line has a 5.30mm width, yet the measurement tool is reporting them as 5.10mm.  When I hover over one of the lines it shows the correct width of 5.30 mm.

Is this a bug or am I just reading it wrong.

[image: png. Don't know how to upload an svg]

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming problem so you may be better off asking it [here](https://inkscape.org/community/) or if you really want a Stack Exchange site, [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Moved.  to Inkscape forum.  Just used to getting good answers from stack overflow.  :)